# Open a Windows 7 notification balloon from batch file - command line

Tags: batch-file, notifications, wifi, balloon

I have simple one-line batch script that loads a wlan profile (xml) to make it easier for our users to connect to our secure wireless network. I still need the users to login, so the profile does not contain user credentials. When the profile is loaded, a Windows notification balloon pops up from the task bar (lower right corner) that says "Additional Information is needed to connect..." as expected. When you click on the balloon, you're given the login credentials pop-up. The title bar of the window is "Windows Security" and the inner title is "Network Authentication. Please enter user credentials". I have seemingly looked everywhere for a way to just open this credentials box instead of the user having to click the balloon. I've run process monitor and I can't find where it adds that balloon to the notification bar. I also cannot find what happens when I click on the balloon and the login prompt comes up. I figured I would be able to add a line to my script that will just skip the click on the notification balloon and bring up the login pop-up. Is it possible to trigger this box? I know I could create my own login box and pass the variables, but I would rather use the native feature if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a wireless interface on this PC to test, but I wonder whether the notification alert is a window with its own handle?  Try using AutoIt's [Window Info Tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to inspect the notification.  If it has a predictable presence, maybe you could script an AutoIt script to simulate a click and do whatever voodoo you need.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try your suggestion, but I did use UI Spy from the Windows SDK. [This](http://i.imgur.com/W5FwJCM.png) is a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for your help, nonetheless. I am confused why my question has a negative rating. It seems like a legitimate question.